# Get all records of a model where its association is not null and the association meets certain conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I am using Rails 3.1.0

I have two models, A and B. 
A has_one B, but B can be null. 
B belongs_to A. 
B has a boolean field called "visible."

I want to get all A records that have a non-null B and a B with "visible" set to true.

What is a concise and efficient way of doing this query?

What I've done so far:

I created a scope that gets the A's with non-null B's (I think).

scope :has_b, includes(:b).where(B.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil))

Is there a way to chain the visible == true condition to this scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A.includes(:bs).where(:bs => { :visible => true })
```

Zach Kemp was almost right

So, in scope:

```
scope as_with_visible_bs includes(:bs)
  .where(B.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil))
  .where(:bs => { :visible => true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'joins' section [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). This query should do what you need:

```
A.joins(:bs).where(:bs => { :visible => true })
```

Comment: It returns collection of dublicated :as